# WCF "The server did not provide a meaningful reply"

Tags: wcf, iis-6, endpoint, basichttpbinding

I am out of ideas here, so I'm hoping someone can help.  Here is what I've got:

- A WCF service that only has a basicHttpBinding endpoint.
- There is only a service interface, all other [DataMember], [FaultContract] are concrete types.
- When I run it straight from Visual Studio (using WCF Test Client or my custom app) everything works (I send a request and get a response).  This usually takes a second or two.
- I published it to an IIS 6 server.
- I can successfully open http://server/WebService/WebService.svc?WSDL
- I can successfully open http://server/WebService/WebService.svc/mex (same output as above)
- The WCF Test Client and my custom app can successfully add the service reference
- Whenever I try to call a service method it waits for about 15 seconds and I get the dreaded "no meaningful reply" error.
- I ran Fiddler and I got a 202 result, which would seem like a success.
- It's not returning more than 65536 bytes
- It's returning an array, but it is small
- I tried remote debugging, but can't get that to work, probably due to a firewall (but port 80 is open, I can get the WSDL)
- I enabled system.diagnostics, nothing.
- I have an IErrorHandler which normally logs things, nothing.

Here's the endpoint config:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Enterprise.IMyService" bindingNamespace="http://ourdomain.com/MyService/">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Anything else I can try? It's probably a simple setting somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

**Edit:**

The raw fiddler response:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Date: Thu, 15 Apr 2010 19:02:45 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: I got this error because an Enum was not initialized to one of the enum "valid" values, i.e. If your enum has only 3 elements, generally the valid values are 0,1,2 (unless you specify other values) Even though the variable would accept any value of the enum underlying type (Usually an Int32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!  It had nothing to do with WCF.  When I moved it to the server the database connection string was no longer valid.  The error logging (to e-mail) configuration also was no longer valid and was eating the exception.  It took 15 seconds to respond because that's how long the SQL server connection took to time out.