# WCF throws error intermittently for the first time whenever I access if after a long time

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF throws below error intermittently whenever I  access the service for the first time in day or after long time.

**"The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."**

Otherwise, it works fine in every case. I am not able to understand why this error occurs?
P.s : I have referred many threads and tried config changes,checked proxy mismatching, but none of them worked for me.
please guide me otherwise I have to put retry option in the service

**Update**
Client config

```
<endpoint address="xxxxx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="IService" name="BasicEndPoint" />

<binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999"
closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" >
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="99999999" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<binding name="BasicEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:03:00" openTimeout="00:03:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:03:00" allowCookies="false"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Service config:

```
 <binding name="Binding1" maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="99999999" />
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF and what kind of biding are you using?

Comment: I am hosting the WCF service on IIS

Comment: @TeisLindemark I have updated the question for you. once again I have tried almost all the binding settings provided in different threads but that not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I have had a lot of strange error messages during the time I have been working with WCF services. What I learned from that is that they do not alwats make that much sense.

When that said, when you describe yur problem, it sounds like one issue I had with one of the WCF services I have worked with that used named pipes. That was a problem related to the activation. Then I had to refresh the service address in the browser then it worked fine. To solve that it was a permission issue.

Anouther thing that have been gining me error messages is that the namespace and contract to the service is correct in the web.config.

When I was googling your error message, there seems like some people get this have issues with enum in the service. I do not think that's your issue, but maybe... [WCF catches exception " The server did not provide a meaningful reply.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793504/wcf-catches-exception-the-server-did-not-provide-a-meaningful-reply)

Comment: no enum in my case. yet checked namespace and contract but it seems to be other issue.